# deb пакет: как задать зависимость в зависимости от версии Ubunt-Ы

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Пытаюсь собрать deb пакет под приложение написанное под net-core.
Для работы приложения требуется установка пакетов libicuХХ в зависимости от версиии Ubunt-ы:
libicu52 (для 14.x)
libicu55 (для 16.x)
libicu57 (для 17.x)
libicu60 (для 18.x)

В деб-пакете можно задать зависимость только не зависящую от версии Ubunt-ы.

Первое что пришло в голову:
Добавить в деб-пакет скрипт "preinst" (скрипт котрый выполняется перед установкой пакета) который-бы и выполнил установку пакета в зависимости от версии Ubunt-ы.
Но при установке такого деб-пакета идет ошибка:
*Не удалось получить доступ к файлу блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend...*
Т.е. из установки деб-пакета не дает ставить другие пакеты скиптом...

Как можно выкрутится в этой ситуации?

Comment: общее правильное решение: создание пакета под каждую версию дистрибутива, которую вы собираетесь поддерживать. оно верно и для частного случая с libicu: пакеты в разных версиях дистрибутивов содержат цифры в названии отнюдь не для того, чтобы создать вам трудности, а ввиду сложностей по [обеспечению обратной совместимости](http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-ICU-Binary-Compatibility:-Using-ICU-as-an-Operating-System-Level-Library)

Comment: но если вы таки справились с проблемами линковки ко всем из перечисленных библиотек (ведь версию в имени содержат и сами библиотеки, и большая часть экспортируемых из них функций), то в зависимостях пакета можете прописать перечисление всех этих библиотек, связывая их логическим условием «или»: `libicu52 | libicu55 | ...`